# Return in the try statement not working?

Tags: java, android, try-catch

In my android application I have this block of code

```
private Date getTimeout() {
        String date = preferences.getString(TIMEOUT, null);
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        if (IsNullOrEmpty(date)) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            Date timeout = timeFormat.parse(date);
            return timeout;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;                //what is this??
        }
    }
```

When i debug my app, I get a strange result, it gets the string, it does the parsing, but does not return the parsed value. Instead, it jumps to the return statement in the catch block. Here how it looks like in the photos. [image]
[image]
As we can see, the timeout object is instantiated normally, so the parsing is done without errors. So why does it jump to the return null statement?

Here, i uploaded a video of my debug also, that can be useful.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oW9hWEnXp2U&feature=youtu.be

Comment: everything looks fine, what's exactly the problem?

Comment: watch the video, it does not return the parsed value, it return null instead. Why?

Comment: are you sure it returns null?

Comment: What does the `e.printStackTrace()` say when/if you end up in the catch block ?

Comment: Does it really return null or is it probably only in the debugger and it actually returns the timeout?

Comment: most IDE debuggers have a hard time with tracking multiple returns statements in a method block (which is why it is good practice to shape ur code to only have one). While it may seem it's jumping to the "return null" line, its just the debuggers way of indicating that the method is finished. Be sure you're getting null by looking at the value from the consuming method, or printing out results to the log.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: ok, thanks guys a lot. I didn't go deeper, it really does not return null, it just shows so. oh yeah, and @X.L.Ant e.printStackTrace() statement does not even take place, that's actually because the method is finished already

Comment: looks like the class you´re debugging does not fit with the java source. clean and try again. Looks like it´s crashind in the parse but you´ve moved one line lower with an import or so and did not compile/refresh